# What is the difference between $state and $stateProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently reading through an `AngularJS 1.4.8`-based application that uses `AngularUI Router 0.2.15`.

I noticed that this application sometimes uses a dependency `$state` and sometimes a dependency `$stateProvider`.

Are there any differences between injecting and working with `$state` and `$stateProvider`?

Comment: `$state` is a service and `$stateProvider` is a .. provider? Short answer: You use `$state` in your controller, `$stateProvider` in your `config`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of singleton instances in angularjs.

One is the service instance we are always using, like $state.

The other one is called the 'provider', like $stateProvider.

'Providers' hold the factory function for the common service and is responsible for creating the corresponding service.

**In other word, $stateProvider creates $state.**

From the angular documentation:

> An Angular **service** is a singleton object created by a **service
>   factory**.  These **service  factories** are functions which, in
>   turn, are created by a **service provider**.   The **service
>   providers** are constructor functions. When instantiated they must
>   contain a  property called `$get`, which holds the **service
>   factory** function.

When angular is instantiating a module, it will first create the providers, and after that it will run the 'module.config' functions.

However, services like $state are not instantiated by that time. They will be instantiated by their providers when needed (e.g. injected into other services) after 'module.config' is finished. So u cannot put a `service` in a `module.config`.

Both `module.service` and `module.factory` are creating providers in fact.They are shortcuts so we can always create services easily.